# Retrieve web user's Identity outside of request scope

Tags: asp.net, iis, integrated-security

I have an ASP.NET app that logs Audit reports using nHibernate's IPreUpdateListener.  In order to set the current user in the Listener events, I was using System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().  This works fine when debugging on my machine, but when I move it to the staging server, I'm getting the ASP.NET process credentials, not the requesting user.

In the ASP.NET page, I can use Request.LogonUserIdentity (which works fine since I'm using integrated authentication), but how do I reference this user directly without having to pass it directly to my event?  I don't want to have to pass this info through the pipeline because it really doesn't belong in the intermediate events/calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is executing in an ASP.NET context, `HttpContext.Current` (static) contains the current Http context. You can always test if it's null or not. If it's not null, you will be able to get `HttpContext.Current.Request`.

However, the identity that resides within this request context ultimately depends on how the web site (IIS, Cassini, IIS express, or custom) handles identity.

Comment: Perfect.  It took me a minute to realize I had to add a reference to System.Web in my project, but everything's working as expected now!